# Проблема при использовании проксируещего реестра pypi.org на nexus

Tags: python, pip, nexus

Использую проксирующий реестр [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) в nexus3 для установки пакетов python.
Пытаюсь установить пакет [dataclasses-jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses-jsonschema/) на РС, где недоступен [pypi.org](https://pypi.org), командой:

```
pip3 install dataclasses-jsonschema --proxy=myrepo/repository/myrepo/simple --index-url http://myrepo/repository/myrepo_ip/simple --trusted-host myrepo
```

Сам пакет уже есть в проксирующем реестре, и корректно устанавливается, если есть доступ к [pypi.org](https://pypi.org).

На РС, где доступа к [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) нет - при попытке установки пакета, сам пакет скачивается из приватного реестра, а зависимости пакета пытается установить из pypi.org.

```
pip3 install dataclasses-jsonschema --proxy=myrepo/repository/myrepo/simple --index-url http://myrepo/repository/myrepo/simple --trusted-host myrepo

Collecting dataclasses-jsonschema
  Downloading http://myrepo/repository/myrepo/packages/dataclasses-jsonschema/2.13.0/dataclasses-jsonschema-2.13.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools_scm/: [Errno 113] No route to host -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: [Errno 113] No route to host -- Some packages may not be found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать переменную окружения, указывающую на ваш прокси сервер

Windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://myrepo/repository/myrepo:80
set https_proxy=https://myrepo/repository/myrepo:443

pip install somepackage
```

GNU/Linux:

```
export http_proxy=http://myrepo/repository/myrepo:80
export https_proxy=https://myrepo/repository/myrepo:443

pip install somepackage
```

**Ссылки**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy-with-cntlm
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server

Comment: Пробовал, это не работает, к сожалению